# How Do I Use VBScript to Strip the First n Characters of a String?

Tags: vbscript

How do I use VBScript to strip the first four characters of a string?

So that the first four characters are no longer part of the string.

Comment: I need to be able to do this on one line of code. Because I am looping through and building an array.

Comment: this line should be sufficient- sText = Right(sText, Len(sText) - 4)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use

```
MyString = Mid(First_String, 5)
```

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner  note that the OP changed his question!

Comment: I can't take back the down vote; but the correct answer to the question (as of now) is: WScript.Echo Mid("aaaaString", 4 + 1) ==> String

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner: I changed my answer to reflect OP question, but I don't understand downvotes.. really

Comment: @Marco: I downvoted your Left() proposal, as it was wrong for the 'get second part' version of the question. After your edit I upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

You have several options, some of which have already been mentioned by others:

- Use a [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2.aspx) replacement:

  ```
  s = "abcdefghijk"
  n = 4

  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Pattern = "^.{" & n & "}"  'match n characters from beginning of string

  result = re.Replace(s, "")
  ```
- Use the [`Mid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3.aspx) function:

  ```
  s = "abcdefghijk"
  n = 4
  result = Mid(s, n+1)
  ```
- Use the [`Right`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eh8fefz1.aspx) and [`Len`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42byt104.aspx) functions:

  ```
  s = "abcdefghijk"
  n = 4
  result = Right(s, Len(s) - n)
  ```

Usually string operations (`Mid`, `Right`) are faster, whereas regular expression operations are more versatile.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (just create sample.vbs with this content):

```
Option Explicit

Dim sText

sText = "aaaaString"
sText = Right(sText, Len(sText) - 4)

MsgBox(sText)
```

Comment: `Mid()` is far easier.

Answer (score 2):

I request you to use the following script to strip first 4 characters of your string
StringName = Mid(StringName,5)