# How to remove first 3 characters in a string

Tags: vbscript

I have a program that prints a string to a notepad file, the output being something random:

`#'f7ruhigbergbn`

I want to however remove the first 3 characters from the pasted result, how can I do this?

```
myString = "#'f"
result = workings - myString
```

This does not work, bare in mind the first 3 characters are always going to be `#'f`

Any thoughts? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
result = Mid(workings, 4)
```

Comment: This answer worked and will be selected in 6 minutes. Thank you

Comment: @Paji.R it's also been [answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8326973/692942), but I'm sure you're not bothered about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Right function for get the X characters of the right side of string. With Len function you can get the length of the string.

```
Right(myString,Len(myAtring) - 3)
```

With this, you get a new string whitout the three first characters, now you can assign to the same string:

```
myString = Right(myString,Len(myAtring) - 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mystring = "#'f7ruhigbergbn"

result = Mid(mystring, 3, mystring.length)
```

Comment: This only removes 2 characters, as Mid starts counting on 1, not 0.